How I can see Miller Plateau Effect on LTspice with MOSFET
Well on reality I have test a circuit with osciloscope and I can easily see the miller plateau on OSC screen like this: gate resistor 130 Ω.

But if I want to see that result on LTspice I cant see any Miller effect. LTspice's result look like pulse generator.

Also I used 3th party MOSFET same as Si2308BDS Nmosfet. This is my lib file for si2308bds
***************************************
* Copyright: Vishay Intertechnology, Inc. *
***************************************
* Jul 14, 2014
* ECN S14-1396, Rev. B
* SPICE Model for Si2308BDS (N-channel MOSFET only)
***************************************
.SUBCKT Si2308BDS D G S
M1  3  GX S S NMOS W=294728u L=0.25u      
RG  G  GX     2.8
R1  D  3      RTEMP 8E-2
CGS GX S      133E-12
DBD S  D      DBD
**************************************************************** 
.MODEL  NMOS       NMOS ( LEVEL  = 3           TOX    = 5E-8
+ RS     = 3.5E-2         RD     = 0           NSUB   = 2.4E17  
+ KP     = 1E-5           UO     = 650             
+ VMAX   = 0              XJ     = 5E-7        KAPPA  = 3E-2
+ ETA    = 1E-4           TPG    = 1  
+ IS     = 0              LD     = 0            
+ CGSO   = 0              CGDO   = 0           CGBO   = 0 
+ NFS    = 0.8E12         DELTA  = 0.1)
*************************************************************** 
.MODEL DBD D (CJO=40E-12 VJ=0.38 M=0.20
+ FC=0.5 TT=1.61E-8 TREF=25 BV=61
+ RS=2.384e-02 N=1.384 IS=3.041e-10   
+ EG=1.185 XTI=1.386)
**************************************************************** 
.MODEL RTEMP R (TC1=8E-3 TC2=5.5E-6)
**************************************************************** 
.ENDS

How can make detailed Miller effect on LTspice?
ANSWER:
as a result I found the solution from comments and answers and it looks fine. thanks alot.



Knowing that LTspice orders node names left to right, top to bottom, from where the node is first visible in the schematic: n001 would be the positive terminal of V2, n002 would be the drain of the MOSFET, and n003 would be the positive terminal of V1. If you want to see the Miller plateau, you'd have to probe node n004, which should be the MOSFET's gate. || Please, in the future, label the nodes of interest instead of keeping them as the default net names; it's not usually this simple to figure out which node is n003. And others might not know the ordering scheme to work it out either.

@Andyaka I think that might be the wrong link; that goes to an answer on a question about the telegrapher's equations that contains no simulation and doesn't even involve any transistors.

@Hearth d'oh. Try this one: simulation that does show miller plateau in case you thought simulators couldn't demonstrate it.


so how can make detail miller effect on LTSpice?

I'm not sure which node are you measuring in the plot (V(?)) but you could measure gate voltage, gate current and load current, for example. A larger gate resistor would make things slower:

Just to be sure the model was loaded and used, since you didn't mention any ltspice error messages, check the proper configuration for your model subckt to be used:



Well you are right. "If I select a value for the gate resistance higher than the normal value I use, the Miller effect starts to become noticeable. However, I don't think this is correct. If you have a MOSFET library that you have tested, could you share it? Thank you."

https://www.vishay.com/docs/68264/si2308bds_ps_revb.zip
